# RESTful route overriden by named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When defining a resources in routes.rb in Rails, I have the following problem: My resource supports the standard CRUD operations and has a custom function/route, which allows filtering. Now this custom routes matches the edit route and jumps in before the actual RESTful route.

Is there a way to prioritize the RESTful routes so that they match first?

```
resources :items do
  get ':category(/:level)', :action => :filter, :on => :collection, :as => 'filter'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just set a simple get route ( if it is a GET request )

```
get 'filter', :to => "items#filter"
```

If you have any problems there are always RoR Guides :)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to RoR guides, I use them on a regular basis but sometimes they just don't cover things - or I just don't find them. In your solution I would need to pick out the params by hand, wouldn't it?

Comment: " In your solution I would need to pick out the params by hand, wouldn't it?". I don't really get what are you trying to ask. If you are asking about how to get to params on your controller action, answer is simple through the `params` helper

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear with that one. You're of course right, the params helper would enable me to pick out the different parameters. On the other hand, I loose the url_for helpers through this route. Stupid me, having a look at it the second time, I can just prefix the route with e.g. 'filter', like so: get 'filter/:category(/:level)', :action => :filter, :on => :collection, :as => 'filter'